# Bringing my app into foreground using react-native

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

When my app is in the background, I will receive an event from the notification panel. After processing the event received, I want to bring my app into the foreground.

> To be more clear about the app - it is a screen recording app using react-native-record-screen. On stopping the recording from the notification list, I will receive an event in the app and save the recorded video, and then I want to bring the app into the foreground.

I did some research, but could n't find a direct way to do this.

A possible solution found is, define a custom URI and open the app using `Linking` from `react-native`.

For implementing the solution, I did the following.

1. Defined a custom URI scheme in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme="my-custom-uri" />
            </intent-filter>
```

2. After processing the event, open the app again using `Linking` API.

```
    Linking.openURL('my-custom-uri://')
      .then(message => console.log(message))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

When opening the app, I'm getting the below error message.

> [Error: Could not open URL 'my-custom-uri://': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=my-custom-uri:// flg=0x10000000 }]

What do I miss here? What additional change is required to open the app using `Linking` API?

Comment: hey man! did you solve that?

Comment: @LucasDalmarco no